# Tensorboard, only show latest tfevents

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Tensboard shows all the events which it finds in the given logdir.

If I ran my training (or whatever) multiple times, I will have multiple tfevents file in the logdir. Tensorboard will show all such variable summaries merged together in a graph which looks strange.

[image: graph]

On stdout, it writes sth like:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Found more than one graph event per run. Overwriting the graph with the newest event.
WARNING:tensorflow:Found more than one "run metadata" event with tag step_0000. Overwriting it with the newest event.
```

How can I make it only show the summaries/events from the latest tfevents file, so that it ignores all older tfevents files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your tfevents files into unique directories with the name of the run, as [documented here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tensorboard/README.md#runs-comparing-different-executions-of-your-model)